# Installing libecwj2-3.3 on Mac

Tags: gdal, ecw

I am trying to install libecwj2-3.3 on MacOS 14.0.
I have added all the patches as well from https://sourceforge.net/projects/libecw-legacy/ bu still the installation is failing with below error.

"/usr/local/libecwj2-3.3/Source/include/NCSDefs.h:430:28: error: static declaration of 'wcsdup' follows non-static declaration"

Am I missing something here?